# How can I change the email address I use to login to my Azure account?

Tags: azure

I have an Azure account e.g. `name@organisation1.com`. I used this to log in to my Azure account. I would like to change this login email to a new email `name@organisation2.com`. Does anyone know how I could do this. I had a search online but I was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/change-azure-account-profile#update-the-email-address-that-you-sign-in-with):

> You can't update the email address that you use to access your account. However, if you have a billing account for an MOSP, you can sign up for another account using the new email address and transfer ownership of your subscriptions to the next account.

Summarily , you can't do that. But as far as I can see, transfering the subscription ownership cover most of the scenarios